# Grails External Configuration. Can't access to external variable. Getting always [:]

Tags: grails, groovy, config

I can't have my 'folder' external variable working. Always I'm getting [:].

I'm developing on Grails under Windows *(this is why the external configuration file looks like file:C:\path\to/file)*.

I'm using external configuration in another project without problems, in the same way that I'm showing below.

I have this:

**Config.groovy:**

```js
environments {
    development {
        grails.config.locations = [ "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy" ]
    }
}
```

**myApp-config.groovy:**

```js
stats.feed.wsdl.folder = '/static'
```

**Controller and Service:**

```js
class WsdlController {
    def wsdlService
    def index = {
        wsdlService.getEventsSchedule()
    }
}

class WsdlService {
    def grailsApplication

    def getEventsSchedule = {
        println "Locations: ${grailsApplication.config.grails.config.locations}"
        println "Folder: ${grailsApplication.config.stats.feed.wsdl.folder}"
    }
}
```

**Console:**

```js
Locations: [file:C:\Users\myUser/.grails/myApp-config.groovy]
Folder: [:]
```

Any clue?

Thanks!

**Updated!**

This is the whole myApp-config.groovy:

```js
println 'Start'
stats.feed.wsdl.folder = "/stats"
println 1
stats.feed.wsdl.folder.events = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder}/events"
println 2
stats.feed.wsdl.folder.teams = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder}/teams"
println 'End'
```

This is not working, the console shows:

```js
Start
1
```

But if I change the variable names, it works.

```js
println 'Start'
stats.feed.wsdl.folder = "${playcall.static.resources.folder}/stats"
println 1
stats.feed.wsdl.events.folder = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder}/events"
println 2
stats.feed.wsdl.teams.folder = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder}/teams"
println 'End'
```

Console:

```js
Start
1
2
End
```

Comment: What happens if you change the location to C:\Users\myUser\.grails\myApp-config.groovy?

Comment: The same.
`Locations: [file:C:\Users\myUser\.grails\myApp-config.groovy]`
`Folder: [:]`

Comment: Just to check if Grails loaded your config file you can put a `println` in `myApp-config.groovy`, so we can see if the file even was loaded.

Comment: Yes, println is showing on console the message I put.

Comment: Ok, I see what is not working, but I don't know why. I have in myApp-config.groovy `stats.feed.wsdl.folder = "/stats"`
`stats.feed.wsdl.folder.events = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder}/events"`
`stats.feed.wsdl.folder.teams = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder}/teams"`. 
I use a `println` between each line and I see that only execute the first one. The execution stops when is trying to set `stats.feed.wsdl.folder.events`. Thanks Sérgio!

Comment: Can you post the full code of myApp-config (edit question)? I tried here and don't have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a property and declared this as a string:

```
stats.feed.wsdl.folder = "/stats"
```

In that way you isnt't able to add subproperties. So, to keep something close to what you want, you can do this:

```
stats.feed.wsdl.folder.base = "/stats"
stats.feed.wsdl.folder.events = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder.base}/events"
stats.feed.wsdl.folder.teams = "${stats.feed.wsdl.folder.base}/teams"
```

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio! You're the best!